# How do you deduce the possible algebraic structures of a group from its order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group G with order 99, G contains the subgroups of order 1, 3 and 11 since they divide 99 and there exist a sylow p subgroup of order 9. Apart from this, what is the relation of order to direct products and isomorphism?
    I dont know if I framed my question well but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It in fact has a normal subgroup of order 11 and a normal subgroup of order 9 (Sylow subgroups). Since both these subgroups have trivial intersection, are  abelian and  the group is their direct product it follows the group itself is abelian. In this case it is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a group of order $99$. From the Sylow theorems it follows that there is only one $3$-Sylow subgroup and only one $11$-Sylow subgroup. Let's say $P$ is a $3$-Sylow subgroup, $Q$ is an $11$-Sylow subgroup. Hence both $P$ and $Q$ are normal in $G$. More than that, $P\cap Q=\{e\}$ and since $|PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}=\frac{9\times 11}{1}=99=|G|$ we conclude that $G=PQ$. So we have all the conditions of a direct product, so $G\cong P\times Q$.

Now, the only group of order $11$ up to isomorphism is $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$, and the only groups of order $9$ are $\mathbb{Z_9}$ and $\mathbb{Z_3}\times\mathbb{Z_3}$.Hence we get that $G\cong \mathbb{Z_9}\times\mathbb{Z_{11}}$ or $G=\mathbb{Z_3}\times\mathbb{Z_3}\times\mathbb{Z_{11}}$, so we actually found all groups of order $99$ up to isomorphism. Of course that can't be easily done for any order, but for order $99$ it is possible as you can see.